# discord.py send a message on reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i coded it that it sends 'test' when someone adds a reaction:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(interaction: discord.user):
    if interaction.emoji == '':
        if interaction.user == client.user:
            return
    else:
        guild = interaction.message.guild
        await interaction.message.channel.send('test')
```

but i always get this error:

```
TypeError: on_reaction_add() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Where is this function called from?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add), the 2 arguments of `on_reaction_add` should be [reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction) and [user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User).

It makes no sense to use interaction here, it's not an [interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction).

Furthermore, referencing [interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction) to the object [discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User) also doesn't make any sense. The colon `:` converts [interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction) to the type [discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User).

Also as a side note, the "u" in "discord.user" should be capitalised, i.e. `discord.User`.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji == '':
        if user == client.user:
            return
    else:
        guild = reaction.message.guild
        await reaction.message.channel.send('test')
```

Read up on: [on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add), [discord.Reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction), [discord.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User)

Comment: it still gives me the same error

Comment: The original error said that the function received 2 arguments when you made it only take one. My corrected code rightly made it take both `reaction` and `user`. Are you sure you're getting the same exact error? If you are, check if you've restarted the bot with the new code and check that there are no other `on_reaction_add` functions defined. If you still face errors, I will need to look at more of your code; definition of client, etc.